# Control.VisibleChanged event not raised

Tags: .net, winforms, events, listview

**Short question:**

I noticed that the Control.VisibleChanged event is not fired when the Visible property changes from true to false.

I've read this article which explains in deep how Visible property is implemented ([link](http://www.scitech.se/blog/index.php/2007/09/19/the-controlvisiblechanged-event/)). This doesn't solve my problem, since I set the Visible property of my UserControl directly, and I don't lie on child visible state event.

What am I missing?

**Long question:**

I have an UserControl containing a ListView with many elements. The ListView is implemented using the virtual mode, so nodes are created only when necessary.

The ListView items shall update theirself when the related object changes; it knows when since the object has a *ObjectChanged* event which notify subscribers whenever the object changed. So, when constructing the ListViewItem, is also subscribe to MyObject.ObjectChanged event.

Sadly, the MyObject instance is almost persistent in memory (never disposed), but the ListView in virtual mode request me to create a lot of ListViewItem representing the same object. Since the created ListViewItem instanced are subscribed to the (persistent) object, they are never disposed, causing a memory leak.

In counterpart, if the created ListViewItem instances don't subscribe the ObjectChanged event, they will be disposed as soon the GC awakes; but this would be a problem, since the node doesn't update itself on changes. A workaround would be possible if the UserControl keep track of created ListViewItem instances, but this would minimize the benefits of the ListView in virtual mode.

*So, I have give up. I'll keep track of every created node.*

Successively, I wanted to reset the ListViewItem collection when the UserControl becomes not visible, but...

[Ref Short Question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't quite follow this, but it sounds like an XY problem.  Using VisibleChanged is tricky, it doesn't follow the value of Visible that you assign.  Only the actual visibility state.

Do not in any way make the ListViewItems aware of the changed state of the underlying data.  I'm guessing you are using a derived class with an event.  Yes, that's going to leak the items if the event source doesn't get collected.  Instead, call the list view's Invalidate() method to force it to repaint itself.  It will raise the RetrieveVirtualItem event again for any visible items so they'll show the updated data.  If you want to optimize this, only calling Invalidate if a visible item is updated, then implement the CacheVirtualItems event.

Comment: CacheVirtualItems give me the range of the actual displayed items after having invalidates the ListView?

Comment: Don't hesitate to try it.  StartIndex and EndIndex properties, tells you what is being viewed.